# Is there a way to set different id for each ValidationError in Django?

Tags: python, django, validation

This is how **my form** looks:

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = [
            'title',
            'content',
        ]

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        title = self.cleaned_data.get("title")
        content = self.cleaned_data.get("content")
        error_dict = {}

        if len(title) < 3:
            error_dict['title'] = ValidationError("testerror1")
        if len(content) < 3:
            error_dict['content'] = ValidationError('testerror2')

        if error_dict:
            raise ValidationError(error_dict)
```

If I try to submit the form with empty `title`  and `content` it shows two error messages (testerror1, testerror2), they appear above each field label and looks like this:

```
<ul class="errorlist">
    <li>test2</li>
</ul>
```

But I want to hide each of them if client click on input, so I tried with Jquery:

```
$("#my_form_id").find('input, textarea').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').hide();
})
```

Without success (it doesn't found any `<ul>` element.

**My question is, is there a way to set different id for each error? So that I can manage each one separately.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* put a unique identifier on each error message, but it is a bit fiddly and I'm not sure how 'safe' I would consider it.
What I think is a better alternative for what you want is iterating over the fields in the form, and rendering the field and the error messages one at a time. The end of this post describes how to do that. If what you really want is to put identifiers on the error messages *without* looping through the fields in the template... well, read on.

### The Hard Way

In order to get more than a simple text message rendered for each error message (without breaking out the form in the template), you need to provide an alternative `ErrorList` class to the `ModelForm`. The `ErrorList` class is what performs the rendering of the errors in HTML, so by creating and using a subclass you can change what gets rendered - including adding a special code from the ValidationError itself.

```
from django.forms.utils import ErrorList
from django.utils.html import format_html, format_html_join

# This overrides the ErrorList class to provide the additional rendering
#  features you want - in this example it only overrides it for the `ul` output
class ErrorListDerivative(ErrorList):
    def as_ul(self):
        if not self.data:
            return ''

        # Key part 1: the UL is now being rendered with a class for
        #  each of the errors which includes the error code from the
        #  ValidationError. You can then locate the UL by looking for that class.
        return format_html(
            '<ul class="{{}} {}">{{}}</ul>'.format(' '.join(('errorcode{}'.format(e.code) for e in self.data))),
            self.error_class,
            # Key Part 2: This adds the code from the validation error to the individual LIs
            format_html_join('', '<li class="errorforcode{}">{}</li>', ((e.code, e.message) for e in self.data))  
        )
```

Now having created an ErrorList that renders things the way you want, it needs to be used by the TestForm.

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # This __init__ is what makes the ModelForm use the custom ErrorList class you've created. 
    #  The BaseForm from which ModelForm is derived (a few layers of inheritence deep) has an `error_class` argument to receive the class used to render errors. This just injects your custom class.
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs_new = {'error_class': ErrorListDerivative}
        kwargs_new.update(kwargs)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs_new)

    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = [
            'title',
            'content',
        ]
```

Then, inside your TestForm clean function, you pass the additional `code` to the `ValidationErrors`

```
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        title = self.cleaned_data.get("title")
        content = self.cleaned_data.get("content")
        error_dict = {}

        # Key Part 3: Here we're including the custom error code in the 
        #  ValidationError, which will be rendered out
        if len(title) < 3:
            error_dict['title'] = ValidationError("testerror1", code='title')
        if len(content) < 3:
            error_dict['content'] = ValidationError('testerror2', code='content')

        if error_dict:
            # Must admit, not sure if adding a code here will do anything at all
            raise ValidationError(error_dict, code='3')
```

Once you have done that, the HTML output should look something like:

```
<form id="my_form_id" method="post" novalidate="">
    <label for="id_title">Title:</label>
    <ul class="errorlist errorcodetitle">
        <li class="errorforcodetitle">testerror1</li>
    </ul><input type="text" name="title" value="ao" maxlength="100" required="" id="id_title">
    <label for="id_content">Content:</label>
    <ul class="errorlist errorcodecontent">
        <li class="errorforcodecontent">testerror2</li>
    </ul><input type="text" name="content" value="ao" maxlength="100" required="" id="id_content">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

With the class now on those ULs, you can use the name of the field to locate the relevant UL and hide it.

```
$("#my_form_id").find('input, textarea').click(function(evt) {
    $('.errorcode' + this.name).hide();
})
```

### The Idiomatic Way

If you don't want to go down that rabbit hole, an alternative is to do something more like the example in the django docs for 'looping over the form's fields' (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields)
It doesn't give you the custom classes (or ids, whatever you end up adding) on the error messages, but it is much more idiomatic.

Something like the following...

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        <div class="errorcode{{field.html_name}}">
            {{ field.errors }}
        </div>
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Then you can use the same jquery as was described above:

```
$("#my_form_id").find('input, textarea').click(function(evt) {
    $('.errorcode' + this.name).hide();
})
```